# class in class - how to get main class variables

Tags: c++

```
class buttonClass {
  HWND hwnd;
  class TextClass {
    const int TextClassMaxLen = 100;
  public:
    operator string () { 
        string windowText(TextClassMaxLen);
        GetWindowTextA(hwnd, (char*)windowText, TextClassMaxLen);
        return windowText;
    }
  };
public:
  TextClass Text;
  buttonClass(HWND parent) {
      HINSTANCE moduleHandle = GetModuleHandle(0);
      hwnd = CreateWindowA("BUTTON", "temp", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 1, 1, 150, 30, parent, NULL, moduleHandle, NULL);
  }
};
```

1. It throws me error upon compilation. It says that hwnd in GetWindowTextA cannot be reached.

How to get hwnd?

2. Is there not any: friend string& operator=(string& paramString, TextClass& paramTextClass);

I do

```
buttonClass button(parent);

string myString=button.Text;
```

I assume there is not operator= so I do it by conversion to string.

What is best way to do it?

Comment: The "class in class" thing is a red herring. How would you solve it, if it weren't class in class, but rather two separate classes? You have to do that here as well. They are 2 different classes. The fact that one is a private class of another class only means, that it is only visible to the said class. Nothing more.

Comment: From what `buttonClass` instance should the `hwnd` member be taken?

Comment: Side note: Don't do this: `(char*)windowText`. I'd almost go as far as saying never use a c-style cast to convert a type. It turns off all of the compilers type defenses and converts the compiler error into a runtime error where it's going to be a lot harder to figure out. I can't be 100% certain that `string` is a `std::string`, but if it is, use the `c_str` method to get a `char*` out of the `string`. With the cast, you've told the compiler that the `string ` IS a `char*`, and it's not.

Comment: It seems like a function such as `FetchText()` would be more appropriate than a data member with a conversion operator. That's what people would expect from the API.

Comment: On rethought, use `string`'s `data` method instead of `c_str`. `GetWindowTextA` needs a non-`const` `char*`. If your tools are older and don't have a `data` method, you can probably use `&windowText[0]`. Technically that's not supported, but I've never seen it not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that accessing hwnd from TextClass is good style, but here is a solution.

Make TextClass a friend of buttonClass.

Change

```
class TextClass {
```

to

```
friend class TextClass {
```

It will then have access to all private member variables in buttonClass.

Comment: but I use operator string() inside TextClass so I dont have given any instance of buttonClass. How to overload this operator and have access to upper class variable? Would there be any code sample? I would like also to overload operator =(int otherInt) and have access to upper class variables